# send errors to sentry with Golang and Mux

Tags: go, sentry, mux

I’m a bit new to Golang, and trying to integrate Sentry with Golang and Gorilla Mux

In the main.go, I added:

func init() {
    raven.SetDSN("https://xxxx@sentry.io/xxxxx")
}
As stated in the doc

Then in my route definition, I add:

```
Route{"get_all_operations", "GET", "/operations", raven.RecoveryHandler(getAllOperations),},
```

In getAllOperations, I generate an error, but I can’t see it on sentry.

I also tried on the first line:

```
raven.CaptureError(err, nil)
```

but I don’t catch any errors. Any idea how should I do it ?

Comment: Can you share the code how you generate the error? Are you using `panic()`?

Comment: I put a wrong data for db connection, so it wont be able to access db. I don't use panic, should I ? so, basically, err is not void, and then I use `raven.CaptureError(err, nil)` I will send you the code on monday !

Comment: Does raven.SetDSN(...) return an error? Also does CaptureError return an error?

Comment: I think I was not generating an error, but now, I am not sure what I have done, but raven.CaptureError(err, nil) is sending error to sentry. Should I understand I will have to refactor each if (err != nil) --> raven.CaptureError(err, nil) in my whole code ?

Comment: SetDSN returns an error, here is the docs: https://godoc.org/github.com/getsentry/raven-go#SetDSN It only checks the syntax of the DSN though, judging by the code.

Comment: Go has no "magic hooks" to catch all err(ors). So yes, you'd have to manually call `CaptureError` for each error. Different story if you want to catch a panic with `CapturePanic`. You can catch panics with [`recover`](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).

Comment: In your code example above you're using `raven.RecoveryHandler(getAllOperations)`. Any panic thrown by getAllOperations would be recovered and sent to Sentry by RecoveryHandler. Only panics, not errors.